# Clicking on an element replaces the displayed content by a new one

Tags: jquery, methods, replace, display

With jQuery, I would like to be able to display on one side a list of clickable elements and on the other side, display a different text depending on the clicked element.
Each click on an element replaces the previously displayed text.

I can't do it.

I tried a lot of things with different methods like show(), hide(), replaceAll(), replaceWith()...

I tried to insert conditions by testing the presence of the element to be displayed.

I couldn't get the desired behavior.

Any idea?

Comment: Okay, so can you share your "*[mcve]*" code (html. css and jQuery/JavaScript) to show us your best attempt so we can try to explain why your attempts failed, and how to work with JavaScript/jQuery and so that we can easily reproduce your problem. How does the text that is clicked determine what to show? Please: take the [tour], and read the "*[ask]*" guidance.

Comment: OKay, I'll take care of that

Comment: I found a solution and it works
I included the html code in a php file that I call when I need it with an include();
Then I have to invoke the load() method to load my file.
I do the same for the few items in my list.

Comment: $('#alpha').on("click", function(){
    $('.text').load('integration_alpha.php');
});

Comment: I am sorry but this way of doing things is depreciated.
It is recommended to use the getScript() or ajax() methods.

I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .html for displaying text from one side to the other side or clicking any element on a page and show text or change anything on the page.

For example.

Some HTML buttons and js code is given below. You can see when you click on any button. The text on the right side will be changed according to the button's text.

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
        var side_text = $(this).text();
        $('.seconed_side').html(side_text);
      });
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex">
<div class="first_side" style="width: 50%;">
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <button>Show Me</button>
    <button>Hide Me</button>
    <button>Save</button>
    <button>Proceed</button>
    <button>Next</button>
    <button>Previous</button>
</div>
<div class="seconed_side" style="width: 50%;">
    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've resolved my problem, thanks